# Moodle Migration Error "Error reading from Database"

Tags: moodle

I have installed Moodle 3.6.3 version on local using XAMPP(V3.2.2).

Now, I want to backup and migrate my moodle site to live domain. So, First I had tried the process on local by following moodle docs (https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Moodle_migration).

After completion of the process and while accessing I am getting an error as

```php
"Error reading from database".
```

**FYI - I had done migration steps as below**

1. Created a new database for migrated moodle and imported old/working moodle DB backup.
2. copied all moodle contents to a new folder i.e, migmoodle.
3. next, copied all moodledata contents to a new folder i.e,
   migmoodledata.
4. finally, I had made required changes in config.php with the migrated
   moodle names and DB details.
5. At last, accessed the moodle and got the same error "Error reading
   from database".

Kindly look into my steps and let me know if I made any mistakes in the migration process.

I am new to Moodle, kindly check and suggest better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to provide more error information about the error, please turn on debugging mode in MOODLE to trace the error.

Please check the moodledata permissions. also, delete sessions and caches folder in moodledata and give it a try.